# Date Range Filter with Datatables Not Working in AdminLte

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, datatable

Script :

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
        function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
            var iFini = document.getElementById('dateStart').value;
            var iFfin = document.getElementById('dateend').value;
            var iStartDateCol = 3;
            var iEndDateCol = 3;
            alert('not working');
iFini=iFini.substring(0,2) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(6,10)
iFfin=iFfin.substring(0,2) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(6,10)       

var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10);
var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10);


            if ( iFini == "" && iFfin == "" )
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin == "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini == "")
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    );


   $(document).ready(function() {
 //datatables account
table_account = $('#table_account').DataTable({ 

    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.

    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('PharmacyController/ajax_list_account')?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },

    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ -1 ], //last column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],

});

$('#dateStart').keyup( function() { table_account.fnDraw(); } );
$('#dateend').keyup( function() { table_account.fnDraw(); } );
  });
```

View :

```
<?php
         $CI =& get_instance();
          $userinfo=$CI->session->userdata('userinfo');
         ?>
        <style> 
       .dataTables_filter {
   display: none; 
   }
   </style>
   <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        Account
        <small>Pharmacy</small>
      </h1>

    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <div class="row" style="padding:20px 20px;">
        <?php
        $this->load->view('message');   
        //print_r($userinfo);
        ?>
        <h1 style="font-size:20pt"></h1>


        <br/>
        <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="col-md-6">
              <form id="form_date_search" method="POST">
                <div class="input-group date">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" name="dateStart" id="dateStart"  class="form-control datepicker pull-right"  placeholder="From">
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="input-group date">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" id="dateend" name="dateend" class="form-control datepicker pull-right"  placeholder="To">
                  <input type="hidden" name="pos_clinic_id" value="<?php echo $userinfo['id']; ?>" />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-12">
              <br/>
            <!--  <center><a class="btn btn-success" onclick="show_transaction()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>Search</a></center> -->
              </div>
              </form>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
        <br/>
        <table id="table_account" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Transaction Id</th>
                    <th>Patient Id</th>
                    <th>Ammount payed</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

        </table>
       </div>



<?php 
include ('modal_view_detail.php');
include ('modal_account.php');
?>
<!-- INCLUDE all modals ends-->
```

I would like to filter the datatable according to the DATE Range Filter . i have a form where we select the starting date and ending date , and with restpect to this the table must be sort out with Date colume in  datatable .
i would also like to tell that the datepicker format is "dd/mm/yyyy" and the date in table also have the same format "dd/mm/yyyy" .

Comment: i have replace " .keyup "  with  ".change"  .

Comment: still not working